# Altium designer direct connect on high power components

Tags: altium, designer, relief, connect, direct

I'm designing a board which I'll solder it by hand.

In order to do soldering much easier I believe that many components need to be connected through relief connect to their adjacent polygon pour.

But, some components are connected to high power circuits, like dc to dc step-down regulator, output capacitor, input capacitor, high side switches, low side switches, etc.

And I think those component it's better to be connected with direct connect.

The question is: I'm trying to find a smarter way to distinguish the connection of the parts instead of putting one by one in the rule builder.

Comment: "I think it's better to be connected with direct connect" - Why? Do you have any proof that this tiny bit of additional resistance/inductance due to it being a thinner track will have an impact? (I'm not saying it wont, just that you should avoid worrying about problems you might not have to begin with)

Comment: You've got a point. That was my first thought but like you said, it was the track width that worried me.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a blanket directive to do that. If you want a certain set of components to share the same rules without having to write a rule for each of them this is the way to go.

1. From Place menu, place a blanket and PCB layout rule
   [image: From Place menu, place a blanket and PCB layout rule]
2. Put it around the selected components you want to have a special rule
   [image: Put it around the selected components you want to have a special rule]
3. Finally enter the rules you want them to have
   [image: Finally enter the rules you want them to have]

I hope this helps you